# Is it possible to implement a block-wise Hilbert transformer using FFT

Tags: fft, hilbert-transform

I'm implementing a discrete Hilbert transformer and I know that an ideal Hilbert transformer is anti-causal and has infinite length so we can only make approximation. There are some FIR and IIR implementations, while MATLAB's `hilbert()` uses FFT to modify the spectrum of input.

What I've done is to keep the DC and Nyquist components, double the components between them and make the negative frequencies zero. But I got wrong results when processing signal block by block. A MATLAB example using windowing and overlap add is given below.

```
fs = 48e3;
Ts = 1/fs;
t = 0:Ts:1;
w = 2*pi*10;
sig = sin(w*t).';
N = length(sig);
y0 = hilbert(sig); % true result using full-length FFT
y1 = zeros(N, 1); % block-wise processing

blockSize = 1024;
hopSize = blockSize / 2;
startIdx = 1;
endIdx = blockSize;
win = hann(blockSize, 'periodic');

while endIdx < N
    x = sig(startIdx:endIdx) .* win; % windowing
    xa = hilbert(x);
    y1(startIdx:endIdx) = xa + y1(startIdx:endIdx); % overlap add
    startIdx = startIdx + hopSize; % 50% overlap
    endIdx = endIdx + hopSize;
end

figure; 
subplot(211)
plot(t, real(y0), t, imag(y0)); legend('original', 'hilbert')
subplot(212)
plot(t, real(y1), t, imag(y1)); legend('original', 'hilbert block-wise')
```

[image]

FIR and IIR filters have filter states saved in the memory which deal with this case, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you implement this as overlap add ?

Comment: @Hilmar No. I take an FFT of N point input, modify the FFT results and do an IFFT, I got N point output for each block. It's not a convolution so I don't get a longer output to overlap add.

Comment: A modification in the frequency domain is a convolution in the time domain.  So you will need to overlap (by the length of the impulse response that is above your desired noise floor or error level).

Comment: @hotpaw2 As far as I know, overlap-add is used in two way -- one is for fast convolution using FFT, which is an LTI system, another one is for time-variant frequency-domain modification, usually required windowing to reduce frequency leakage. In my current code I used OLA in the second way. Do you mean that I should treat it as the first way, just like a convolution?

Comment: @hotpaw2 When I do `y0 = hilbert(sig);` the default FFT point is equal to the length of `sig`, while calculating linear convolution using FFT requires a FFT length of `N+M-1`, where `N` and `M` are the lengths of `sig` and the unknown impulse response respectively. So I don't think this process is a convolution.

Comment: It's a property of any FFT, IFFT, DFT, or IDFT.  A multiplication is one domain is identical to a circular convolution in the other domain.  (Or a linear convolution, if sufficiently zero-padded, as in overlap-add.)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is in implementing the Hilbert block by block in either case (using MATLAB's `hilbert` or own method) then this would properly be done using [overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or overlap-save block processing techniques. Here in this case the combination of windowing with the overlap and add (as commonly done) reduces the edges of greatest distortion in the Hibert implementations. This is implemented by following the pseudo-code in the above link for the implementation of linear convolution by replacing the FIR impulse response in that link with the Hilbert impulse response as described further below. The windowing I mention would be the windowing of the ideal time delayed and truncated Hilbert impulse response as would properly be done in the implementation of an FIR Hilbert using the windowing design approach.

If the issue is with replicating the Matlab `hilbert` implementation with FFT processing, below is an FFT implementation of the Hilbert in MATLAB that I confirmed produces an identical result as the `hilbert` function:

```
N = length(sig);
sig_spectrum = fft(sig);
hilbert_spectrum = zeros(1, N);
hilbert_spectrum(1) = sig_spectrum(1);
hilbert_spectrum(2: ceil(N/2) - 1) = 2 * sig_spectrum(2:ceil(N/2) - 1);
if mod(N, 2) == 0
  hilbert_spectrum(N/2) = sig_spectrum(N/2);
endif
hilbert_time = ifft(hilbert_spectrum);
```

Another approach is to simply implement the filter directly as an FIR filter since we know the coefficients are given by the impulse response, which for the Hilbert is given as:

$$h(t) = \frac{1}{\pi t}$$

As the OP mentioned this is non-causal and thus for implementation as FIR filter coefficients, the above impulse response is sampled, delayed and truncated (and windowed to reduce sidelobes).

[image: Hilbert Implementation]

One "trick" if we already have a half-band filter in our pocket, is we can easily convert it to a Hilbert by taking the absolute value of the coefficients, setting the largest center tap to 0 and negating all the taps left of center:

[image: half band to hilbert]

Comment: Yes but sorry Dan, I got the same result just as `hilbert` when taking the full-length FFT for the long input signal. But things went wrong when I do it block by block.

Comment: @DSPnovice What do you mean "Block by Block"--- you take the Hilbert of a block and then you do it with the FFT approach of that same block and you don't get the same result? What is the FFT in that case that is different from a "full-length FFT"? Isn't this the same thing-- just the total number of samples changes? Note the careful handling of the Nyquist bin depending on if the block length is even or odd, is that perhaps your issue?

Comment: @DSPnovice Please try my code to see if you get a different result for your smaller block-- if not, maybe if you provide an example in your question the issue might be clearer.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: `y0` is not equal to `y1` in my example even when I use MATLAB's `hilbert`. That's my main problem.

Comment: @DSPnovice I see where you are trying to do it now. It is incomplete, please compare to my solution, I believe this is the answer you are looking for.  Each "block" you would process identically where nearly half the samples are zero, proper handling of DC and Nyquist bins etc.  If you want to do alternate FIR based approaches without the FFT, I added that to my answer as well.

Comment: `y1` is initialized as zeros and the assignment is in the loop.

Comment: @DSPnovice Can you please try my code. I believe it is correct. Make it a function and run it just as you run `hilbert`-- you will get the same result.

Comment: Sorry Dan, I believe that your code is equal to `hilbert`, since I wrote my own which deals with the Nyquist carefully according to odd or even of FFT length and got the same results as `hilbert`, **only when** I send my input signal into the function at one time, like `y0` in my example. When I send it block by block using a while loop, **both** methods fails to give correct results, like `y1` in my example.

Comment: I think maybe I should use something like overlap-add just as Hilmar said, but I don't figure it out how to do it. BTW, FIR is fine, just wondering if FFT works for this block-wise case.

Comment: @DSPnovice Ah I see; I misunderstood- you're problem isn't with your implementation of the Hilbert but in how to do an FFT in general ---which then yes overlap-add or overlap-save especially if each block is windowed, would be the typical approach. So similar here with the Hilbert as with windowing the overlap would properly process the edge samples. I believe windowing would be beneficial as well for you in this case with the overlap to reduce the effects of the bad edges.

Comment: @DSPnovice I updated the intro to cover that with a link to the pseudo-code for overlap-add.  You can follow that example exactly showing linear convolution replacing the FIR coefficients with your Hilbert coefficients. The windowing I suggest would be the windowing of the Hilbert impulse response which you would do regardless as a proper FIR implementation of the Hilbert.

Comment: Unfortunately I try to use a Hann window and 50% overlap-add but still get weird result. Please have a look at my edit.